# Error con el spinner y la caja de texto

Tags: android

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, tengo un pequeño problema con el spinner lo carga muy bien, pero antes de escoger el dato lo muestra en la caja de texto, este es el código que se se utiliza:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtid);
    txtfechadenuncia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtfechadenuncia);
    txtfechasiniestro =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtfechasiniestro);
    txtsiniestro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtsiniestro);
    txtinspeccion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtinspeccion);
    spcodigo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spcodigo);
    spinspeccion = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinspeccion);
    cmdbuscar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdbuscar);
    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    ArrayList<String> seleccion = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion.add("Seleccion");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion);
    spcodigo.setAdapter(adaptador);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion1 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion1.add("Selección");
    seleccion1.add("No");
    seleccion1.add("Si");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador1 = new ArrayAdapter (this, R.layout.spininspeccion,seleccion1);
    spinspeccion.setAdapter(adaptador1);
    spinspeccion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            txtinspeccion.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}
```

al ejecutarlo queda de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el sipinner de spinspeccion con letra azul, es donde tengo la duda porque lo carga enseguida si no se ha realizado ninguna opción todavía, favor de asesorarme y desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que en `onCreate()` que es el punto donde inicia tu app, estas en realizando la inicialización de los datos en el `spinner`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador1 = new ArrayAdapter (this, R.layout.spininspeccion,seleccion1);
    spinspeccion.setAdapter(adaptador1);
    spinspeccion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()  
    ...
    ...
}
```

Puedes realizar una función que se llame mediante un botón por ejemplo donde le indiques cargar los datos al spinner, con esto evitas que se cargue al iniciar tu app.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda y comentario, lo tengo entendido que es así, pero debe haber alguna forma para que no se traspase el primer add del spinner a la caja de texto, revisando a través de la web y varios indican que en el cambio de posistion poner -1, lo hago así también pero se cae la app, desde ya muchas gracias